# Google Structured Data Testing Tool is repeatedly warning me about failing to include mainEntityOfPage in JSON-LD

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

Have I misunderstood what `mainEntityOfPage` represents in schema.org?

I thought it told user-agents what the parent page of a given entity is, *if* the **entity** being described by structured data *is the **main entity** of a given page*.

But every time I mark up in `JSON-LD` an entity which is *not* the main entity, Google Structured Data Testing Tool warns me:

> The `mainEntityOfPage` field is recommended. Please provide a value if
>   available.

So I get multiple repeated warnings recommending that each non-main entity should have a `mainEntityOfPage` entry.

Which... makes no sense at all.

Unless I have misunderstood what `mainEntityOfPage` represents in schema.org.

Am I allowed to include something like:

```
"mainEntityOfPage": "false"
```

---

**Example:**

```
<body>
    <h1>I am a Webpage</h1>
    <p>I am an introduction to the webpage.</p>

    <article>
        <h2>Article One</h2>
        <p>As an article I am very important. In fact, I am the Main Entity of this Webpage</p>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h2>Article Two</h2>
        <p>I am another article on this Webpage, but I am not as important as Article One</p>
    </article>
</body>
```

When I add structured data in JSON-LD about **Article Two**, I see the error:

> The `mainEntityOfPage` field is recommended. Please provide a value if
>   available.

which (I think?) is saying - *you need to tell me: Article Two is the Main Entity of... what page?*

But... Article Two isn't the Main Entity of *anything*. It is a less important entity of the webpage for which Article One is the Main Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it’s the case with most of the warnings/errors from the SDTT, this warning is [only relevant if you want to get a specific rich result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41418157/1591669).

In this case, it seems to be for Google’s [Articles rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#article_types), which recommends to use `mainEntityOfPage` on AMP pages. If you don’t use AMP, or if you can’t provide all of the required properties, or if you don’t care about the rich result, you can ignore the warning.

Your understanding of `mainEntityOfPage` seems to be correct, and your use seems to be correct, too: only provide it for articles that are the primary entity on some page.

I think your case is unusual, though. Typically *each* article has a dedicated page. This page might provide data about additional articles (show teasers etc.), but these additional articles all would have their own page somewhere.

If you really have a page with two articles, and neither of these articles has another dedicated page, and both articles are self-contained, and the page is primarily only about one of these articles, then your structured data should be fine.

Comment: A brilliant answer, @unor - thank you very much indeed. You answered my main question and also my lurking suspicion (_is Google generally anticipating no more than one article per page...?_)